# Converting GOCAD .ts file to raster for ArcMap Analysis

Tags: raster, dem, tin, cad

I have a multi-layered (10 layers) GOCAD .ts file of data that I would like to convert into a series of rasters. The documentation says it requires a program capable of reading

> GOCAD * .ts (triangulated surface) files.

The data is elevation data of the surface and sub-surface geologic units in the Great Artesian Basin of Australia. I tried to drag it into ArcMap and tried to use the TIN to raster tool, but it wont recognize the .ts extension.

How do I convert this bad-boy to a raster for each layer?

Here is a link to where the data can be downloaded from the official provider:

> https://ecat.ga.gov.au/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/metadata/75990

I use R for some of my image processing if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenGeoSys](https://www.opengeosys.org/) offers converters to read GOCAD .ts files and export them as raster data.

In my Windows10 OS, I have [downloaded](https://www.opengeosys.org/releases/) OpenGeoSys (.zip) and extracted the file to 'My Documents' folder (`"C:\Users\userr\Documents"`) and also saved the GOCAD file to (`"C:\Users\userr\Documents\GOCAD_file"`).

(1) Start Command Prompt (shell) and move to the `bin` folder.

```
cd "C:\Users\userr\Documents\ogs-6.3.0-Windows-10.0.14393-x64-de-utils\bin"
```

(2) Run a command to read the file

```
GocadTSurfaceReader  
 -i "C:\Users\userr\Documents\GOCAD_file\3DVIS_LAYER01_3SEC_DEM.ts" 
 -o "C:\Users\userr\Documents\GOCAD_file"
```

This command will produce `01_GABWRA_DEM.vtu` which is in VTK format.

(3) Export this interim VTK (.vtu) file as a raster (ascii) file. (output cell size = 4000m).

```
Mesh2Raster  
 -i "C:\Users\userr\Documents\GOCAD_file\01_GABWRA_DEM.vtu" 
 -o "C:\Users\userr\Documents\GOCAD_file\01_GABWRA_DEM.asc" 
 -c 4000
```

[image]

However, I found myself with a big problem here... GOCAD file does not carry CRS information with it, and there is no information in the linked Geoscience Australia website. Hope you can find appropriate CRS for this.